# Ionic 3 data update between apps

Tags: ionic3

I'm new to ionic, I have two ionic v3 apps. App1 is Customer app(user orders food). app2 is restaurant app(restaurant accepts order). How do I communicate between these apps. App1 has a button "order", how will app2 know the details and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

you need to create services to store and retrieve data from a server where your app1 will communicate to the server to store the data of order and from app2 i.e.resturant app will retrieve the data from the server. If you don't like to create services or don't have a server you can integrate firebase to store and retrieve the data.

If your services are already ready and you just need to store the data to server you can use httpclient

```
storeOrder(data,token){


return this.httpClient.get("SERVER_URL"+data, {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('ApiKey', token)})
  .map(res=>res)
```

}

```
retreiveOrder(token,orderid){


return this.httpClient.get("SERVER_URL"+orderid, {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('ApiKey', token)})
  .map(res=>res)
```

}

Kindly elaborate your question in more detail so that i will understand where exactly you are stuck

Comment: That's great, I did that at first and it was working fine. I need to send push notifications to the respective mobile app and vice versa. "eg: if app1 clicks "order" it should get notified in "app2" and should fetch data accordingly." I'm currently searching for an MQTT example for implementing. I could use GCM/APN but since Facebook uses MQTT I'm trying to go with that approach.